# How to write OR operation in sqwrl query

Tags: owl, ontology, reasoning, swrl, sqwrl

For AND operation in sqwrl query, it is like :

`Symptom(fever) ^ Symptom(vomiting) ^ Disease(?y) ^ hasSymptom(?y,fever) ^ hasSymptom(?y,vomiting) -> sqwrl:select(?y)`

From the above rule, it is selecting the diseases that have both symptoms. What about OR operation in sqwrl query? I want to select the diseases that has either symptom fever or symptom vomiting? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer  to select diseases that have either symptom vomiting or fever.

`Symptom(fever) ^ Symptom(vomiting) ^ Disease(?x) ^ Disease(?y) ^ has_symptom(?x, fever) ^ has_symptom(?y, vomiting)˚sqwrl:makeSet(?s1, ?x) ^ sqwrl:makeSet(?s2, ?y)˚sqwrl:union(?s3, ?s1, ?s2) ^ sqwrl:element(?e, ?s3) -> sqwrl:select(?e)`

Answer (score 1):

I think, what you are searching for can be done with [collections](https://github.com/protegeproject/swrlapi/wiki/SQWRLCollections#Disjunction). With them you can define a disjunction. I am not sure but maybe your desired query looks like this:

```
Symptom(?fever) ^ Symptom(?vomiting) ^ Disease(?x) ^ Disease(?y) ^
hasSymptom(?x, ?fever) ^ hasSymptom(?y, ?vomiting) ˚
sqwrl:makeSet(?s1, ?x) ^ sqwrl:makeSet(?s2, ?y) ˚
sqwrl:union(?s3, ?s1, ?s2)
-> sqwrl:select(?s3)
```

Comment: I am getting this exception :
error running SQWRL queries: error running Drools rule engine:

Comment: However, I read the documentation on collections and I build another rule:
Symptom(fever) ^ Symptom(vomiting) ^ Disease(?x) ^ Disease(?y) ^ has_symptom(?x, fever) ^ has_symptom(?y, vomiting)˚sqwrl:makeSet(?s1, ?x) ^ sqwrl:makeSet(?s2, ?y)˚sqwrl:union(?s3, ?s1, ?s2) ^ sqwrl:size(?n, ?s3) -> sqwrl:select(?n)   

I ain`t getting any exception and it is returning me the correct result for the size. BUT it is not working when selecting s3.